# ModelChoiceField always raises : "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices"

Tags: django, forms, modelchoicefield

i have a ModelChoiceField that containts clients names selected from my database.
but when submiting the form i get :

> "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices"

here is my form :

```
class FormVents(forms.Form):
  client_name=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=client.objects.all().values_list('nom', flat=True),required=False)

  def clean(self):
     client_name = self.cleaned_data.get('client_name')
     print(client_name)
```

i tryed to print client_name to check if i can get the value but i get None ! i guess that's why i always get that error 
Dont know what's the problem? is the way i call the field is not right ? 
any help please . Thank You so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `.values_list('nom', flat=True)`.

IE

```
client_name=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=client.objects.all(), required=False)
```

If you want the `value` attribute to be a particular field from the model (the primary key is used by default), use the [`to_field_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name) keyword for the modelchoicefield.

For example,

```
client_name=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=client.objects.all(), to_field_name='nom', required=False)
```

Comment: Thank You So much, You really Helped me a lot.